# Extract Customer ID from Stripe JSON response in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, stripe-payments

Since Stripe doesn't have a way to lookup a customer based their email address, I have to pull all of them down and compare accordingly ([from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767150/stripe-is-it-possible-to-search-a-customer-by-their-email)).  This works fine, but now `customer_i_need` is:

```
[#<Stripe::Customer:0x3fc836b51efc id=cus_8BETSKddddnJD> JSON: {
  "id": "cus_8BETSKddddnJD",
  "object": "customer",
  "account_balance": 0,
  "business_vat_id": null,
  "created": 1459377705,
  "currency": "usd",
  "default_source": "card_17us0SDcysUdddff5P8gqGmWm",
  "delinquent": false,
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "email": "bobby@test.com",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "shipping": null,
  "sources": {"object":"list","data":[{"id":"card_17us0SDcysUdddff5P8gqGmWm","object":"card","address_city":null,"address_country":null,"address_line1":null,"address_line1_check":null,"address_line2":null,"address_state":null,"address_zip":null,"address_zip_check":null,"brand":"Visa","country":"US","customer":"cus_8BETSKddddnJD","cvc_check":null,"dynamic_last4":null,"exp_month":1,"exp_year":2019,"fingerprint":"aHBJ0hDddffdaB9","funding":"credit","last4":"4242","metadata":{},"name":null,"tokenization_method":null}],"has_more":false,"total_count":1,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_8BETSKddddnJD/sources"},
  "subscriptions": {"object":"list","data":[{"id":"sub_8BETB4CWTlBert","object":"subscription","application_fee_percent":null,"cancel_at_period_end":false,"canceled_at":null,"created":1459377705,"current_period_end":1490913705,"current_period_start":1459377705,"customer":"cus_8BETSKddddnJD","discount":null,"ended_at":null,"metadata":{},"plan":{"id":"annual_600","object":"plan","amount":60000,"created":1459172660,"currency":"usd","interval":"year","interval_count":1,"livemode":false,"metadata":{},"name":"annual_600","statement_descriptor":"Trial","trial_period_days":365},"quantity":1,"start":1459377705,"status":"trialing","tax_percent":null,"trial_end":1490913705,"trial_start":1459377705}],"has_more":false,"total_count":1,"url":"/v1/customers/cus_8BETSKddddnJD/subscriptions"}
}]
```

really, I just need to be able to add the `id` (cus_8BETSKddddnJD) to my users account if it's already created, but I'm having trouble accessing the value.

I've tried `customer_i_need["id"]` but that's not working.  I've also tried to convert `customer_i_need.to_json`, then access the value the same way, but that's not working either... where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you get some instance of `Stripe::Customer` returned. I would expect that you can just call `id` on that instance:

```
customer_i_need.id
```

Or since it looks like the instance is the only element in an array:

```
array.first.id
```

Comment: O, holy moly!  That was way to easy!