# How to use SquareSpace for login on Python Program

Tags: python, api, squarespace

Is there any way to have a login on my python program that accesses my squarespace site?  For example, I have a game that costs 4.99, and I want to make sure that no one can “copy-paste” my program, so I add a login.  This login would connect to SquareSpace, and check if the account used to log in bought the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a Squarespace website through which you are selling the game. That being the case, customer information could be accessed from a different service/server via a couple methods:

1. **Squarespace Commerce API**: Use of the [Squarespace Commerce API](https://developers.squarespace.com/commerce-api) currently requires an "Advanced Online Store" plan from Squarespace, costing $40-$46/month at time of writing. If that is an option, you can obtain order information from your Squarespace site and use it to verify customer purchases.
2. **Stripe API**: Because customer payments through your Squarespace site will be processed via Stripe, it should be possible to use the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api?javascript=false) to access order/payment information as well. However, it may be more difficult depending on how Squarespace is submitting the information to Stripe.

It appears possible to [filter customers by email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767150/stripe-is-it-possible-to-search-a-customer-by-their-email), though I've not explored this option myself. If this method works, it would avoid having to pay for a Commerce - Advanced plan through Squarespace, a significant cost for access to such a basic set of API features.

Comment: Thank you so much.